# Pass variable via Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I pass a variable (`$member_id`) to the target php page(Member Profile details Query)?

```
///-----



 echo '<div id="show_profile_box">Show Member Profile details 
        //MySQL Query to display member profile details</div>

    <div id="display_member_id"><a href="show_profile.php"?member_id=$member_id">Display Member id</a></div>';

echo '<script>
    $("#show_profile_box").hide(100);
    $("#display_member_id").click(function () { 
        $("#show_profile_box").show(500); 
    });
    </script>';
```

Thank you. Let me know if you need more info.

*** The whole idea is to display/show SELECTED member profile details. ***

Comment: How is this question related to jQuery or MySQL? Is `$member_id` PHP variable?

Comment: From my very little experience with PHP, it should be something like `...<a href="show_profile.php"?member_id=' .$member_id . '">.....`

Comment: Remember the page doesn't get refreshed so it has to be added via Ajax but I can't figure it out.

Comment: So where exactly is `$member_id` defined? What is its value? I thought it's existing variable with predefined value, sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the safest way of passing arguments from server-side PHP to client-size JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613186/what-is-the-safest-way-of-passing-arguments-from-server-side-php-to-client-size-j)

Comment: It's defined in member profiles details php page but the issue is passing the $member_id variable to it via anchor<a> without refreshing the page.

Comment: @Yanick. They are not the same question. Infact they are totally different questions. This is a different approach.

Comment: @Frank, then I got you a nice answer. Still, there if you look the "Related" questions (on the right side (just here --->) you might just find some very related questions anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using single quotes. Single quotes do not parse PHP variables. When outputting multiline HTML from PHP, use heredoc :

```
echo <<< END_OF_HTML
<div id="show_profile_box">Show Member Profile details 
   <!--MySQL Query to display member profile details -->
</div>

<div id="display_member_id">
   <a href="show_profile.php?member_id={$member_id}">Display Member id</a>
</div>

<script>
    $("#show_profile_box").hide(100);
    $("#display_member_id").click(function () { 
        $("#show_profile_box").show(500); 
    });
</script>
END_OF_HTML;
```

Also, note that the variable do not have to be enclosed by `{}` but still a good practice to do so.

This will create a link like "`show_profile.php?member_id=3`" that, if you click on the link, will call the script with the `$_GET['member_id'] = 3`. You can even get the page content via a XHR call inside your `click` event :

```
$.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) { /* process data here */ });
```

Comment: Tried it. On clicking the link goes to show_profile.php page. This is not what I want. I want it to show show_profile_box with which contains <!--MySQL Query to display member profile details -->. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank, your `click` event must return `false` if you don't want to follow the link specified within it's `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You've added a querystring key/value for member_id so you can access the $.GET variable on your PHP page to retrieve the member_id as such:

$member_id = $.GET["member_id"];

Example of the AJAX functionality you're looking for:

```
$.GET("show_profile.php?member_id=<your_member_id>", null, function(data){
    $("#show_profile_box").html(data);
});
```

Comment: Yes but how do I pass this variable to the php page via javascript?

Comment: If you don't want to send the user on to another page (display it inside your #show_profile_box) then you'll have to use AJAX to get the information from the server and display it.  See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var member_id = <?= $member_id ?>;
</script>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you correctly, you need to do this in php:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">memberID =' . $memberID . ';></script>;
```

I assume that you want to do this on some specific action like click so you specify a js function in the onlick handler which takes the value of the global JS variable memberID and makes an AJAX call to your other page.